# REST based data storage/retrieval server side component out of the box?

Tags: database, rest

I am looking for a server side component, that handles storage of data of different types. I have already written such a component from scratch in Java (at work). Now I am interested in having such a component ready to install, because I want to concentrate on wirting the client side in a small project as a hobby.

Some details: I have a couple of different object types (around 5 to 10) that are connected via ids.
The clients should be able to send/receive data in JSON via http using the following types of commands:

- Get documents by ids
- Submit a new document
- Update a document
- Optional: Given a time stamp, request a list of ids of documents that have been changed since that date

It should be possible to restrict some operations to specific users (i.e. updating existing documents). Thus some kind of simple authentication/group model is probably needed there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Or [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/). Or [mongodb](http://support.mongolab.com/entries/20433053-rest-api-for-mongodb). Or [couchdb](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API).

Not sure about the authentication + authorization modules. Maybe you should wire up the backing storage with a reverse http proxy, which has such plugins.